# Android - Popup menu when list item view pressed?

Tags: android, android-listview

i would like to implement a popup menu similar to google's play store as shown below.

[image]

so basically from what i understand, i'll need an activity and a layout for this activity with a listview defined in it. i need to create my custom adapter. also, i need to create a list layout would contain the information and a view (with the 3 dots) that will serve as the button to launch the popup menu? the issue that i'm seeing here is that how do i create a listener for this view only and how do i reference the value for that specific list item in the list view.

i don't have any code available yet as i haven't started anything related to this. i'm currently getting info in theory for now but if required i will create a sample code.

thanks.

Comment: you can open pop up menu onItemClick method of listview.

Comment: fist start then come back after u have tried something..And go through listView tutorial.Be practical

Answer (score 22):

Using [popup menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) it's quite simple to create a menu with these three steps:

**1 -** Add a click listener to the menu button using `OnClickListener` or as i prefer from the layout xml:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/menu_button" android:onClick="showMenu" ... />
```

**2 -** Create the menu layout **menu_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_settings"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_about"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="About"
        android:visible="true"/>
</menu>
```

**3 -** Create a popup menu, inflate the xml layout and show it:

```
public void showMenu (View view)
{
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (this, view);
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener (new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener ()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick (MenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.item_settings: Log.i (Tag, "settings"); break;
                case R.id.item_about: Log.i (Tag, "about"); break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    menu.inflate (R.menu.menu_layout);
    menu.show();
}
```

Comment: elegant answer, simplest one i hv found ! Saved my day

Comment: How to show icons with the options menu? The `android:icon` is not working for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView_Actions;
    ArrayList<String> actionsArrayList;
    Button btn_ViewPopUp;
    ArrayAdapter<String> actionsAdapter;
    static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID1 = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_ViewPopUp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ViewPopUp);

        actionsArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        actionsArrayList.add("Action 1");
        actionsArrayList.add("Action 2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        btn_ViewPopUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID1);
                actionsAdapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_actions, actionsArrayList);
                listView_Actions.setAdapter(actionsAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID1:
                dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_actions);
                listView_Actions = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView_Actions);
                break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {
        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> actionsArrayList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId,actionsArrayList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_list_cell, null);
            final TextView lblContactAction;
            lblContactAction = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContactAction);

            lblContactAction.append(actionsArrayList.get(position));
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Now XML files:

**action_list_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContactAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
         android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DB6A16"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView_Actions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nice...! I use same method. :)

Comment: Hi i have used your code inside Fragments but  
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) Method is not present in Fragments , what should i do ?

Comment: Now showDialog is deprecated. use PopupMenu instead

Answer (score 8):

**ActionBarCompat List PopupMenu**  implementation is **[here](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu/index.html)** (with back port available because it uses ABC)!

[image]

You can also get this sample from [Github](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Android-Developers-Samples/tree/master/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu) or from SDK *(Mr.Morgan commented below)*

> /sdk/samples/android-19/ui/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu. Make sure to
>   install Samples for SDK under Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

Comment: Where to get this example ?

Comment: @zest This example can be found in `/sdk/samples/android-19/ui/ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu`. Make sure to install _Samples for SDK_ under _Android 4.4.2 (API 19)_.

Answer (score 4):

first of all you need to make your custom adapter with a view that has the 3 dots.

then in the getView() or newView() method you set the listener to the 3 dots image.

i think that [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) is what you are looking for, it's is supported since API 11.

if you want to support also earlier version of the API you can use [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) class provided by the [support library v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

the usage is pretty straight forward.
you define it with the id of the view you want the menu to show next to, and then you can directly inflate a menu resource there as if it was a common menu.

Answer (score 2):

Now showDialog is deprecated, use PopupMenu instead
And AppCompat PopupMenu f you want to support version before V11

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
Button button1;  

         @Override  
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

          button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method  
         }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Listener of the Button in the getView()-Method of your List-Adapter.
In this getView()-Method you assign a Layout to one List-Item. if you have done this, you just have to set the Listener on this View (Button), and handle the onClick() Event.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you correctly but you can trigger this method to open a pop up dialog with a listview.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Title if Any");
    builder.setItems(R.array.listoptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemClicked) {
                   String[] option_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listoptions);

                   String optionSelected = option_array[itemClicked];
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

See **[Adding a List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="listoption">
    <item>Install</item>
    <item>Add to listview</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps.