# Perform actions in gridview on list popup menu item select

Tags: android, adapter, popupwindow

I want to add actions in a list popup menu, like [with Play Store App in this POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588781/android-popup-menu-when-list-item-view-pressed).

I have succeeded it very well, but i'm facing a serious problem.

I want to do some actions in my `GridView` item after clicking on an action.

[image]

I tried to do that in my adapter, by passing `position` parameter of `getView` method to my `onListItemClickListner`. But i notice that the `position` 's value remains unchanged after grid gets initialised.

```
public View getView(int gridPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        // some code

            mAdapter = new PopupMenuAdapter(context, popupData);
            popupWindow = new IcsListPopupWindow(
                    context);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.list_popup_shadow));
            popupWindow.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            popupWindow.setModal(true);

            popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new PopupListItemListner(id));
            // upon clicking on a button, show the popup menu :
            holder.shortcut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    // show popup menu:
                    popupWindow.setContentWidth(activity.getWindowManager()
                            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 3);
                    popupWindow.setAnchorView(v);
                    popupWindow.show();
                }
            });

        // ...

        return rowView;
    }
```

I don't know how can i do it.