# Is it possible to show context menu at position of item in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I have a listview. I want to click a item and show a context menu at click item position. Currently, I am using the below code to show context menu and perform some action when I click the item. It works well but the context menu position is automatic setting at center of my screen. How can I fix it?

```
public class ManageActivity extends Activity {
  private ListView mainListView ;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_main);    
    // Find the ListView resource. 
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );     
    registerForContextMenu(mainListView);
 }
  @Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
      menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
      menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
     AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acm = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     String  audio_file_name = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(acm.position);

     if(item.getTitle()=="Edit")
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Edit Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if(item.getTitle()=="Delete")
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how long is the screen? i am trying to ask "are you sure?"

Comment: I want to do it in long click event.

Comment: well then i think you call your context menu on that particular view, not the whole listview

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. A perfect example is gridview items in Google Play App. Basically, you can find more details here:

[Android - Popup menu when list item view pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18588781/2507646)

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.setonItemLongClickListener();` then you anchor your popumenu to it